# Error assignment to expression with array type in C

Tags: arrays, function, types, variable-assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
 int diff [8];
    int experiment[8]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,};
    int measurements[8] ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int counter;
    int socre;
    char output;
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[0]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[0]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[1]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[1]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[2]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[2]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[3]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[3]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[4]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[4]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[5]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[5]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[6]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[6]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[7]);
    scanf("%d",&experiment[7]);
    printf("Congratulations ! you have all done.here is the result");
    printf("\nReal value for 0 : 100 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[0]);
    printf("\nReal value for 1 : 100 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[1]);
    printf("\nReal value for 2 : 200 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[2]);
    printf("\nReal value for 3 :  50 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[3]);
    printf("\nReal value for 4 :  90 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[4]);
    printf("\nReal value for 5 : 265 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[5]);
    printf("\nReal value for 6 :  45 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[6]);
    printf("\nReal value for 7 :  56 ! but your experiment value is : %d",experiment[7]);
    printf("Please wait........");
     {
       diff=abs(experiment[2]-100)*100 /100;
        if (diff<1)
        {
         printf("\nThe score is = 8");
        }
         else if(diff<10)
        {
           printf("\nThe core is = 4");
        }
         else
        {
          printf("\nThe score is =0");
        }
     }
    return 0;   
}
```

I got **[Error] assignment to expression with array type** once I compile this. The error line is **diff=abs(experiment[2]-100)*100 /100;**

Could you please also tell me the shortest path to print my experiment values and get outputs (using for loop)?  If you can't fix this, please re-write the code for me. I've attached a [link](http://postimg.org/image/6snh6bo33/) to this homework question.

Comment: Thanks brother !! it's working !! perfect help !!!

Answer (score 1):

!!! `int diff [8]` !!!

Change it to `int diff;` to pass the compilation.

P.S.

You know that `*100 /100` is the same as `*1`, right?

Regarding the loops, take a look at the following tutorials for arrays and loops (do such things by yourself):

http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-arrays-arrays-and-loops

http://www.idleloop.com/tutorials/introC/introC-10.php